# In SQL Server, how do I copy a row's data into a new row with a change to one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I see that this has been asked in some form or another but I'm not getting it, I guess.

Simply, I have a table with a single row:

```
ID    PET_NAME    PET_DESC            OWNER
1     Kibbles     Rat-faced possum    Bixby
```

I'd like to copy that row and change the owner's name so that it looks like this:

```
ID    PET_NAME    PET_DESC            OWNER
1     Kibbles     Rat-faced possum    Bixby
2     Kibbles     Rat-faced possum    Dweezle
```

How do I accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: ideally you will have a table for Pets and a table for owners. looking at your current schema... the ID is associated the owner which is really a bad design. keeping in mind the Many to Many relationship with the owners and pets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ID` is an `identity`.

```
insert into T (PET_NAME, PET_DESC, OWNER)
select PET_NAME, PET_DESC, 'Dweezle'
from T
where ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use system_user as well to replace the hardcoded owner name. It will user name who is executing the query

INSERT INTO TNAME (ID,PET_NAME, PET_DESC, OWNER)
SELECT ID,PET_NAME, PET_DESC,SYSTEM_USER
FROM TNAME
WHERE OWNER IN ('Bixby')

--mention the owner names to add as new